# Does MousePosition["Graphics"] give coordinates in outermost Graphics?

Tags: eventhandler, dynamic

It seems that this issue has been raised a few times, but what exactly does MousePosition["Graphics"] answer?

This code

```
Dynamic @ p
 Graphics[
 EventHandler[
  Disk[], {"MouseMoved" :> (p = MousePosition["Graphics"])}]]
```

nicely displays mouse position in the "current graphics" coordinate.

But try to put the graphics in another Graphics (GraphicsColumn in this case):

```
Dynamic @ p
GraphicsColumn @ 
 List @ Graphics[
   EventHandler[
    Disk[], {"MouseMoved" :> (p = MousePosition["Graphics"])}]]
```

The coordinates now seem to be in the coordinate system defined by GraphicsColumn.

I will greatly appreciate any answer with a workaround (even not so generic solution).

P.S. Interesting enough GraphicsColumn breaks LocatorPane behaviour. LocatorPane manages to get correct coordinates (it uses custom LocatorPaneBox) but locators do not display:

```
pts = {};
GraphicsColumn @ 
 List @ LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], Graphics[Circle[]], 
   LocatorAutoCreate -> All]
Dynamic[pts]
```

Comment: Whenever possible I try to use `Row`, `Column`, and `Grid` directly instead of their `Graphics` variants for other reasons.  This works as expected, ```Column@{Dynamic@{p,p2},Graphics[EventHandler[Disk[],{"MouseMoved":>(p=MousePosition["Graphics"])}],Frame->True],Graphics[EventHandler[Disk[],{"MouseMoved":>(p2=MousePosition["Graphics"])}],Frame->True]}```, but it doesn't have head `Graphics` so it might not work for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

In the example above

`MousePosition["Graphics"]`  should be changed to `MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}]` to limit the coordinate system to the innermost expression with head `Graphics`.

Unfortunately this does not work either.

After the discussion with the developers this was reported to WRI.

Comment: Have you ever heard back from this? Just discovered that this is still not fixed and also appears for other things than Graphics, e.g. Panes...

Comment: @AlbertRetey unfortunately it's still "in progress"

Comment: OK, I was afraid so, thanks for sharing...